# Python Sigma Sums

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of values 
x=`[1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1]`
and I have another blank list
`y=[ ]`

I am trying to create a function that will take a sigma sum of values in `x` and store them in `y`.

For instance, `y[0]` should be the sum of `x[0]*x[0] + x[0]*x[1] + x[0]*x[2] + ... + x[0]*x[9]` .

Similarly, `y[1]` should be the sum of `x[1]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1] + x[1]*x[2]+ ... + x[1]*x[9]`.

This has to be done for `y[0] through y[9]`.

Also, in the sums, `x[i]*x[i]` must be zero. So for instance in `y[0]`, `x[0]*x[0]` has to be zero. Similarly, in the sum for `y[1]`, `x[1]*x[1]` must be zero.

This is my code, but it always gives me some sort of error regarding indices:

```
x=[1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1]
y=[]
def list_extender(parameter):
    for i in parameter:
        parameter[i]*parameter[i]==0
        variable=numpy.sum(parameter[i]*parameter[:])
        if variable>0:
            variable=1
        if variable<0:
            variable=-1
        y.append(variable)
    return y
```

Then i run `print list_extender(x)` which should print list `y` with the sigma sums described above, but I always get an error. What I am doing wrong?
The help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post the full traceback? (For one thing, you're missing an end parentheses in the `sum` line). Another issue is that the line `parameter[i]*parameter[i]==0` does literally nothing (it just compares `parameter[i]*parameter[i]` to 0 and does nothing with the result.

Comment: Parentheses has been fixed. Now it returns y as a list of zeros, but that is not supposed to be the outcome.
So how do i change it to have `parameter[i]*parameter[i]` to actually be zero and have an effect on the result?

Comment: By "`x[i]*x[i]` must be zero", do you mean that `x` must consist entirely of zeros, or are you trying to say that you want to exclude `x[i]*x[i]` from the computation of `y[i]`?

Comment: @user2357112 I would like to exclude x[i]*x[i] from the computation

Answer (score 7):

You're doing way too much typing and computation here. Your function could be shorter and simpler if you computed the sum of `x` first, then used that to compute the elements of `y`. It'd also run faster.

Just do this:

```
x_sum = sum(x)
y = [item * (x_sum - item) for item in x]
# or, if you really want to store the results into an existing list y
# y[:] = [item * (x_sum - item) for item in x]
```

Replace `sum` and the list comprehension with numpy operations if you're using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1])
y = x * (x.sum() - x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this should be right. I've broken it out into two comprehensions for readability:

First, get the sum for x[n]:

```
def s(l): return sum([l[0]*l[i] for i in range (2, len(l))])
```

Now, simply pass in the sublists of x:

```
def sigma_sum(l): return [s(l[i:]) for i range (len(l)-1)]
```

This returns the list [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1]

Which is correct: going backwards from x[8]*x[9], we get -1. -1+1 = 0. -1+1+(-1) = -1, and so forth.

Comment: Your result is not correct. It should be `[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought the question was progressive. Easier than I thought, then. Actually, it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers did a good job at doing what you want with python. Here is a way to do it with numpy, by using the outer product:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1])
a = np.outer(x, x)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 0.)
result = a.sum(0)
```

Which gives:

```
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

You can then convert this to a list if you must.

I timed this solution with the other pure python version from @Ashwini Chaudhary. Here are the timings for you 10-element list:

```
numpy:  10000 loops, best of 5: 29.4 us per loop
pure python: 1000 loops, best of 5: 119 us per loop
```

And for a 100-element list:

```
numpy: 10000 loops, best of 5: 72.7 us per loop
pure python: 100 loops, best of 5: 9.67 ms per loop
```

So it ranges from being 4-130x faster.

Comment: Could you test out `x * (x.sum() - x)`? I'm afraid I don't have access to a numpy installation at the moment. (I'm not even sure `x.sum() - x` works like I think it does.)

Comment: @user2357112, I tested and it is indeed correct. Much better!